# Magento - Filter categories by visibility

Tags: magento, filter, visibility, categories

How can I get only categories that are visible in frontend (Include in Navigation Menu -> set to yes). I've the following function to get the category names and urls.

```
function getCatLinks($id){

    $_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $cats = $_model->load($id)->getChildren();
    $catIds = explode(',',$cats);

    $categories = array();
    foreach($catIds as $catId) {
        $category = $_model->load($catId);
        if( $category->getIsActive() ) {
            $categories[$category->getName()] = $category->getUrl();
        }
    }

    ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
    return $categories;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please don't explode the cats! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you need:

```
$category->getIncludeInMenu();
```

Comment: perhaps somewhere near `$category->getIsActive()`